# Azure CLI to Deploy Function, non fatal error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-deployment

I am using Azure CLI command to deploy function code from a ZIPped artifact. Here is the code, nothing major just an az command and the location of the artifact.

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $RGName -n $FnName --src "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Artifacts/drop/EventHubFunction.zip"
```

However, when I am using that in a pipeline, I get a random ***non fatal*** error; i.e. the pipeline does throw an error, but it silently continues and the function gets deployed. I am just curious to know what this error means and what can I do to avoid this. The error I am faced with is,

> 2019-04-18T13:00:17.7925065Z ##[error]WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
>
> 2019-04-18T13:00:20.7587414Z ##[error]WARNING: Starting zip deployment
>
> 2019-04-18T13:00:20.7633968Z ##[error]

**Please Note**, I am using an Azure Powershell Task, using az login using a service principal and then using az functionapp deployment. I could use Azure CLI task I know, but my logic is a bit more complicated to extract the FnName, as I need to loop through and deploy several instances of the function and Azure CLI task does not like *foreach*

Comment: Can you try with --debug to get more info related to the error.

Answer (score 0):

In regular Powershell commands you can use the CommonParameter -ErrorAction Stop But for the AzureCli az command i think you can use a simple if statement:

```
if (az login --service-principal -u $ClientId -p $ClientSecret --tenant $TenantId)
{
   "Success"
}
     else {"Error"}
```

Or check the last exit state using the $? Automatic variable after the login attempt:

```
if (!$?) {"Error"}
```

similarly for function deployment too, you can achieve it.Also try using the --query operator to check for things you need.E.g.

```
# Create the Web App if it does not already exist
if(-Not (az webapp show --name $webAppName --resource-group $resourceGroupName))
{
    az webapp create --name $webAppName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --plan $servicePlanName --tags 'displayName=WebApp'
}
```

Hope it helps.